# Adding input files from within a gawk action

Tags: awk, gawk

Given something akin to the following files:

file A:

```
module modA;
include file B;
include file C;
[more stuff]
end module;
```

file B:

```
value x=5;
value y=7;
include file D;
[etc.]
```

file C:

```
value z=10;
value title="A string";
[etc.]
```

file D:

```
value x1=15;
[etc.]
```

I want to be able to use `gawk` to catch the `include file` lines, print them out, and then have `gawk` read through that new file that was found, or at least add it to the list of files as though it were on the command line. The output would look something like this:

```
A: B
A: C
A: D
```

My question is: how do I get `gawk` to read through files B, C, and D without knowing *a priori* that it needs to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming every line of `file` is a file name, this will execute `do stuff` on every file whose name is contained in `file`.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ ARGV[ARGC] = $0; ARGC++; next } { do stuff }' file
```

If this isn't waht you want edit your question to describe your requirements better (and lose all the domain-specific terminology like `specialty dependency generator for Motif UIL files` as that just obfuscates your question, it's all just records and fields or rows and columns to the rest of us) and to provide specific sample input and expected output.

Given your updated question, see the example I give of recursive-descent parsing at http://awk.info/?tip/getline:

```
 awk 'function read(file) { 
        while ( (getline < file) > 0) { 
            if ($1 == "include") { 
                 read($2) 
            } else { 
                 print > ARGV[2] 
            } 
        } 
        close(file) 
  } 
  BEGIN{ 
     read(ARGV[1]) 
     ARGV[1]="" 
     close(ARGV[2]) 
 }1' file1 tmp
```

The above not only expands all the lines that say "include subfile", but by writing the result to a tmp file, resetting ARGV[1] (the highest level input file) and not resetting ARGV[2] (the tmp file), it then lets awk do any normal record parsing on the result of the expansion since that's now stored in the tmp file. If you don't need that, just do the "print" to stdout and remove any other references to a tmp file or ARGV[2]. In this case, since it's convenient to use $1 and $2, and no other part of the program references any builtin variables, getline was used without populating an explicit variable. This method is limited in its recursion depth to the total number of open files the OS permits at one time.

Let us know if you cant figure out how to tweak that to suit your needs.

Comment: Rephrased the question, hopefully explaining what I'm looking for better.

Comment: This is art! I also liked the recursive-descent parsing reference.

Comment: This pretty much did the trick. I got rid of the `else` after `if ($1 == "include")` because I wanted to collect those lines, which I did with a simple `$1 == "include" { print origFile ": " $2 }`. I still need to tweak the output, but that did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, ok, this is not awk but I can't resist:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -0
$_=<>;    
while( s/include\s+(\S+);/`cat $1`/e){ }
print
```